# How to create a curved screen effect like this one in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

How can I create a curved screen effect like this one in Photoshop CC 2018?

[image: effect I'm trying to achieve]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load your "screen" into Photoshop (I added in basic border as well)

Now extend the crop of the image a bit (So you have some more space for the curvature)

[image]

Then go to **Filter > Lens Correction** and select *Custom*

Adjust the *Remove Distortion* between +5 and +15

[image]

Result (+8) :

[image]

---

For further realism I would suggest making the border of the screen with a subtle gradient and even applying a mostly transparent gradient on the whole screen.

Also adding a drop shadow would help.

Some more "playing around" and fine tuning

[image]

There's an ultra heavy chromatic distortion effect in your image. It's not like chromatic aberration in lenses, it's more like poor RGB convergence in old CRT displays. If that's wanted, you can scale Red, Green and Blue channels differently:

[image]

- Select all
- Go to Channels panel (**Window → Channels**) and close other channels than R.
- Use *Edit > Transform > Scale* and scale R channel image to 100.5%.
- Leave G as is and scale B channel to 99.5%

Comment: I added a little about the chromatic distortion effect. Feel free to remove it or write it to more slick form.